# jQuery Mobile listview not initializing

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a `ul` on a page with `data-role='listview'` however it is not being initialized by jQuery Mobile to be a listview when the page loads normally or thorough jQM's ajax refresh.

If it helps I'm using rails 3 and haml. The line in question is

```
%ul{:data => {:roll => 'listview', :inset => 'true'}}
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.0.

Comment: should you write role instead of roll ?

Comment: If I weren't an idiot, yes. Thanks @pdjota. Maybe it's time I took a vacation :-p

Comment: well, perhaps a break would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with `haml`. but should that perhaps be `role` instead of `roll`?

Comment: Please excuse me while I hang my head in shame. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: Some times you just need a different pair of eyes to catch something.